# Setting Second-Level Bullet Indent in Microsoft Word 2008

Tags: macos, microsoft-office-2008, microsoft-word-2008

I am trying to set the indent of the second level of bullets in my "List Paragraph" style to 1". I was able to modify the first level by:

```
Style >> Modify >> Paragraph
```

However, there does not appear to be an option to modfiy the second level. The paragraph and bullet screens are not particularly helpful either. I attached images of my screens below. Anyone have any advice?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens in `Customize` in the bullets screen? Its been a while since ive used MS office

Comment: @KarthikT. I updated my question to reflect that screen. There does not appear to be an option for a second level of bullets.

Comment: does [this](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/bullets/controlbullets.html) help? Section 2 talks abt this. Or [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/creating-multilevel-numbered-lists-in-word-2011-fo.html) - mac but abt numbered lists

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you click Modify from the Style screen (the first one)?  In Word 2011 for Mac, this brings up a Modify Style screen that allows you to edit any of the levels:

[image: Screenshot]